# Laravel Lighthouse @middleware above v5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-lighthouse

Before the update, we were using `@middleware(checks: ["permission:admin"])`, which was working fine. We are planning to upgrade Laravel and Lighthouse. The documentation suggests using `@guard`, but it is not working. How do I apply the `permission:admin` middleware in Lighthouse v5 and above?

```
extend type Query @middleware(checks: ["permission:admin"])
```